# Combining result rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the result below to be displayed group by Article.
Would this be possible?
So that in the end I will only have 2 lines.
The data from TYPE I & W will be combined.

The image to my query as below
[image http://tikistudio.sg/F002.jpg](http://tikistudio.sg/F002.jpg)

The query as below

```
SELECT INTSALEID as RECEIPT,
    STRSALETYPE as TYPE,
    STRORDERCODE as ARTICLE,
    max(case when strsaletype='I' then DBLQTYSOLD else null end) as [QTY SOLD],
    max(case when strsaletype='I' then CURSELLPRICE1 else null end) as [UNIT PRICE],
    max(case when strsaletype='W' then CUROFFERDISCOUNT else null end) as [DISCOUNT],
    max(case when strsaletype='I' then CURFOREIGNAMT else null end) as [GROSS AMOUNT]
FROM DAILYSALES 
WHERE STRTRADECODE='MM01' 
  and DTMTRADEDATE='01-01-2015' and INTSALEID='31086'
  and STRSALETYPE in ('I','W')
GROUP BY STRORDERCODE,STRSALETYPE,INTSALEID,DBLQTYSOLD,CURSELLPRICE1,
    CURFOREIGNAMT,CURDISCOUNT,CUROFFERDISCOUNT
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove some columns in Group By

```
SELECT 
   INTSALEID as RECEIPT,
   STRORDERCODE as ARTICLE,
   MAX(CASE WHEN strsaletype='I' THEN DBLQTYSOLD ELSE NULL END) as [QTY SOLD],
   MAX(CASE WHEN strsaletype='I' THEN CURSELLPRICE1 ELSE NULL END) as [UNIT PRICE],
   MAX(CASE WHEN strsaletype='W' THEN CUROFFERDISCOUNT ELSE NULL END) as [DISCOUNT],
   MAX(CASE WHEN strsaletype='I' THEN CURFOREIGNAMT ELSE NULL END) as [GROSS AMOUNT]
FROM DAILYSALES 
WHERE 
STRTRADECODE='MM01' 
and DTMTRADEDATE='01-01-2015' and INTSALEID='31086'
and STRSALETYPE in ('I','W')
GROUP BY STRORDERCODE,INTSALEID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aggregate your data one more time grouping by Receipt, and Article, taking the max value for QTY Sold, Unit Price, Gross Amount and Min Value for Discount.

```
Select RECEIPT, ARTICLE, MAX([QTY SOLD]) as [QTY SOLD], MAX([UNIT PRICE]) as [UNIT PRICE], MIN([DISCOUNT]) as [DISCOUNT], MAX([GROSS AMOUNT]) as [GROSS AMOUNT]
From
(select INTSALEID as RECEIPT,
STRSALETYPE as TYPE,
STRORDERCODE as ARTICLE,
max(case when strsaletype='I' then DBLQTYSOLD else null end) as [QTY SOLD],
max(case when strsaletype='I' then CURSELLPRICE1 else null end) as [UNIT PRICE],
max(case when strsaletype='W' then CUROFFERDISCOUNT else null end) as [DISCOUNT],
max(case when strsaletype='I' then CURFOREIGNAMT else null end) as [GROSS AMOUNT]
from DAILYSALES 
where STRTRADECODE='MM01' 
and DTMTRADEDATE='01-01-2015' and INTSALEID='31086'
and STRSALETYPE in ('I','W')
group by STRORDERCODE,STRSALETYPE,INTSALEID,DBLQTYSOLD,CURSELLPRICE1,
CURFOREIGNAMT,CURDISCOUNT,CUROFFERDISCOUNT) x
Group by RECEIPT, ARTICLE
```